# Problem with graphql and the spring boot context

Tags: java, graphql-java

I'm build a graphql application using the spring-boot framework integration.

Basically I have this graphql type:

```
type Customer {
    id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    address: Address
}
```

With a POJO that mapping all the types.
My resolver just call the constructor of the object passing the id field, that is a parameter of the query.

The information about the object address is a request for an external API so, I only want to get when the query has for address:
example:

```
{
  Customer(id: 123456) {
    firstName 
    lastName
    address {
      number
    }
  }
}
```

So I put some logical code in my getAddress method of the customer POJO.

When my getAddress is executed, all the beans for spring is not initialized, so i get a nullPointer.

What I'm doing wrong?

Is this the correct way to populate my object? Using the get method?

That for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how spring manager the objects.
My POJO Customer, is initialized by me, with new word and in this case, spring could not manager the dependency of my objects, so e got a nullPointer.

When I pass the responsibly to Spring, using @Autowired my dependency start to work.

So, Spring does not manager your objects.